# How to change a property getter at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, mono, reflection.emit

I have a class with a property that looks like this:

```
public class Hmd{
    Transform HmdTransform{
        get{ device.GetTransform(); }
    }
}
```

`device.GetTransform()` gets the Transform from a driver.

Now I want to change the get method of the property at runtime, to something like:

```
public class Hmd{
    private Transform hmdTransform;
    Transform HmdTransform{
        get{ return hmdTransform; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do that? I would have to create a new member and change the getter. If I can't create a new member could I just change the `device.GetTransform()` line?
 I assume I would have to use Reflection.Emit?

Additional complication: All of this is in Unity, so I can only use Mono.

Comment: This seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What do you actually need? Why can't you have the private field at compile time?

Comment: You could supply a `Func<Transform>` to the class that the property will call. That way you can pass in whatever you like to it. But, as Camilo says, this is likely overkill for what you're trying to achieve here. If you give more context, we could suggest a better solution.

Comment: Definitely an XY problem. What is the real problem that you are trying to solve with an obvious dirty hack?

Comment: I know this sounds strange and like I should probably approach this from another angle (make requirements for classes instead of changing them after the fact) BUT I'm building a replay system and my main goal is to make as little assumptions as possible about the members I want to record (which worked thus far). The problem arises when I want to feed my data back into objects that got the data in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 2):

You can't *rewrite* properties as such - you can't monkey-patch in .NET.

Options:

- inheritance; use `TypeBuilder` to create a type that subclasses `Hmd` and overrides the `HmdTransform` accessor that you would need to make `virtual`
- simpler - just add an override property, so something like:

  ```
  public class Hmd{
      Transform HmdTransformOverride {get;set;}
      Transform HmdTransform{
          get{ return HmdTransformOverride ?? device.GetTransform(); }
      }
  }
  ```

or perhaps simpler still:

```
public class Hmd{
    Transform _transform;
    Transform HmdTransform{
        get { return _transform ?? device.GetTransform(); }
        set { _transform = value; }
    }
}
```

This allows the single property to serve both purposes; when not set (or when explicitly set to `null`) the default behaviour applies, but it can be given an explicit value.

Comment: This at least answers the question if it's possible. Couldn't really find that and was confused what was possible with Emit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Func<Transrom>` to replace property.

```
public class Hmd
{
    Transform _transform;
    Func<Transform> HmdTransform;

    public Hmd()
    {
        HmdTransform = HmdTransfromA;
    }

    public void SwapHmdTranformGetWay()
    {
        if (HmdTransform == HmdTransfromA)
        {
            HmdTransform = HmdTransfromB;
        }
    }

    private Transform HmdTransfromA()
    {
        //TODO A Solution
        return null;
    }
    private Transform HmdTransfromB()
    {
        //TODO B Solution
        return null;
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
 var hmd =new Hmd()
 var A = hmd.HmdTransform(); // Get Tranform By A Solution
 hmd.SwapHmdTranformGetWay(); // Change Get Tranform Way
 var B = hmd.HmdTransform(); // Get Tranform By B Solution
```